# SQL Server 2012 (compability level 110) and SQL Server Native Client 10

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, odbc, compatibility-level, native-client

I've upgraded my SQL Server 2008R2 to SQL 2012. I will set the compability level to 110 (2012) to all databases.

But I'm wondering if it will create some problems for clients that connect to this server with SQL Server Native Client 10.0 ?

I saw on multiple forums that they only won't be able to use new features of SQL 2012 but they never speak about level of compatibility of databases.

Can someone give me some clarification ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The client library used to connect does not care at all about the compatibility level of the database.

The code *issued* by the client may have some issues (for example, you needed 90 to use APPLY many years ago). But the mechanism used to send the code and get results does not care